# Joi - validate property against value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

Im trying to validate a value of a particular property in a payload against a defined array of objects.

for example

payload

```
{
    a:[1, 2]
}
```

the value of "a" must be a one of the id defined in a array of objects (multiple values allowed)

```
[
        {
            "id":1,
            "share":{
                "x":100,
                "y":0,
                "z":0
            }
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "share":{
                "x":90,
                "y":0,
                "z":10
            }
        }
        ....and so on
]
```

Could you please help advising if this can be achieved with Joi?

Thanks, Gowrish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joi's [array.validate()](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.4.0/API.md#array---inherits-from-any) with items should do what you're looking for.

```
const Joi = require("joi")

const input = { a: [ 1, 2 ] }
const objects = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]

const schema = {
  a: Joi.array().items(Joi.any().valid(objects.map(o => o.id)))
}

const result = Joi.validate(input, schema, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error:', err)
    return
  }
  console.log('result:', result)
})
```